# Offered my first full-time software job and it comes with some responsibility. How should I approach?

Tags: software-development

I have been working as a freelance web developer on and off for the last ten years whilst holding down a career in construction management. I mainly concentrated on making Wordpress websites. I left my job a year ago to focus heavily on the freelance work as well as improving my knowledge of modern Front-End development frameworks.

Skip forward to a few months ago I started looking for a full-time role. I didn't apply for everything, only the jobs that really seemed suited to myself. I got a couple of code tests, the first of which I provided a perfect front end website to spec, but was let down by a bit of back-end work. The second I was told my solution wasn't up to scratch, but later found out the recruiter had pitched me for a £60k salary!

The start of this week I was approached by a recruiter who had an opportunity for a JS developer. I sent my resume over and got a phone interview. Upon speaking to the company, I think they took a shine to me and I made it through to a technical interview where I was tested and then told about the role a bit more and how they were really interested in finding someone who was a culture fit.

They are after someone to come in and be the sole JS dev for the UI of the projects they were doing. It would be my responsibility to handle the UI of their product as well as maintain the company website. They were worried I wouldn't have enough work to keep me going full-time so are offering to let me also learn their speciality languages (Python) which is a language I have been wanting to learn for a while but never have really found the right opportunity.

Upon speaking about tech, they were open about the fact they didn't necessarily understand the stack and were looking for someone who can come in and own that side of the work. They had a contractor who had been there and he had been using Angular and Node but moving forward I could approach things any way I wanted. I mentioned I have some experience with Node, mainly self taught and they were happy for me to work on those skills whilst there.

It sounded perfect, almost too good to be true! I never believed for a second I would be offered the job the next day.

Its a very good salary, and I am so excited for the opportunity. I am also very aware that this offers a bit more responsibility than an initial position would usually offer. I am confident I am a mid-level for skillset and also the fact I have some experience working to client deadlines from freelancing and having held a career in management.

So far my reservations are:
- Learning new tech on the fly. I don't want to hold anything up whilst I figure new things out.
- Working in a development environment and sticking to the correct way of doing things.
- Maintaining the code that is already there. I don't have too much experience with this.

I tell myself that I was 100% honest with the company and they wouldn't have chosen me if they didn't think I was capable but then self-doubt creeps in. I just want to be as prepared as I can be before I start in a months time.

I am nervous more so than I have been about anything before. With your knowledge how would you approach this situation?

Comment: It might be worth trimming down your text to the key points. Are you concerned you won't pick up what they do quickly enough? Do you get the impression they won't give you that time to adjust?

Comment: @Kozaky I think he's just a bit nervous, not that he's foreseeing problems with the employer.

Answer (score 4):

Don't be unduly nervous, you were up front about yourself so your skills won't let you down. Now prove you have a work ethic and social skills as well and settle down and do the work.

Don't go in making excuses before you start. Self-confidence will be your biggest asset until you're up to speed, without it you will struggle. So back yourself to succeed, you have the most stake in it.

Answer (score 2):

**It sounds like you are suffering from "[imposter syndrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impostor_syndrome)".**

Don't doubt your abilities if you have laid out what you know and they think you can do the job.

Paraphrasing your question:

> **Is it reasonable for a mid-level dev to be expected to:**
>
> 1. Learn new tech on the fly.
> 2. Work in a development environment and stick to the correct way of doing things.
> 3. Maintain the code that is
>      already there.

All of these are reasonable expectations that I think you will encounter in pretty much any developer role. This profession is very much about ability to learn. Take your time and show particular care to the practices and rules in place.

Ultimately, these are rivers you will *have* to cross.